# Rollup/Sapper/Svelte: get list of routes and all sub-components after compilitation

Tags: svelte, rollupjs, sapper

How do I get the list of required components for all existing Sapper routes and its compiled file name from the rollup process?

Background: I am optimizing my website load performance by preloading required resources at first load via HTTP2 Link and NGinx push. When I analyze the waterfall network load, I see that after the main html being loaded, a client.*.js loads, which then imports the main route component e.g. index.*.js.... after that the index file loads the sub-components. So we have a tree of components loaded reflected 1-on-1 in the network waterfall chart. At the time the request hits the server for a specific route, basicilly the route component and all its sub-components could theoraticilay be known and thus be preloaded via http link. How to know which route and component files are corresponding to the demanded sapper route?